# How do I test w/rspec Request Spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to write an rspec functional/request to test the fact that after filling in a form to create a record in the "VIN" model, the user is redirected to the edit_path for the record that was just created.   Here is my current test:

```
    describe "Add VIN" do
    it "can be added on the VIN listing page" do

        sign_in_as_a_valid_user
        vin = FactoryGirl.create(:vin)

        current_path.should == vins_path
        page.should have_field("vin_text_box")
        fill_in "vin_text_box", :with => "hello"
        click_button "generate_vin"
        current_path.should == edit_vin_path(v.id))   <---- #problem
    end
end
```

The obvious problem is that my Factory-created vin has no bearing on the vin that is redirected to.

So the question is, how can I test this functionality in a request spec?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most recently created `Vin` from the database.

```
# ...
click_button "generate_vin"

v = Vin.order("id desc").first
current_path.should eq(edit_vin_path(v.id))
```

Comment: Thanks.   I guess this method works.   However, if I'm in a situation where I'm running different test suites simultaneously, there is no guarantee that the most recently created Vin is the one I just created.  Correct?  I guess I can cross that bridge when I get there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example from RelishApp: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Widget management" do

it "creates a Widget and redirects to the Widget's page" do
    get "/widgets/new"
    expect(response).to render_template(:new)

    post "/widgets", :widget => {:name => "My Widget"}

    expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:widget))
    follow_redirect!

    expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    expect(response.body).to include("Widget was successfully created.")
  end

end
```

See how they do? Change :show, to :edit and test the integrity of your page instead of whether or not your controller chose the right @vin. You will get that by passing FactoryGirl a specific value for one of its attribute.